# Transferring Music to Ipod Touch without Installing iTunes on Windows

Tags: ipod-touch, transfer

Is there any software that can be used to transfer music from a computer to an iPod touch without requiring installation of any apple software?

MusicMonkey and the foobar plugin all require installing iTunes.

What's the least fussy way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [DoubleTwist](http://Www.doubletwist.com); you can use it without having anything else installed. It's free and works on both Mac OS X and Winows.

Answer (score 1):

[Best iPod-compatible iTunes alternatives](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-12519_7-10104294-49.html)

[iTunes Alternatives](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2007/11/08/itunes-alternatives/)

[List of the Best Free iTunes Alternatives](http://crenk.com/list-of-the-best-free-itunes-alternatives/)

[10 Alternatives to iTunes for managing your iPod](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/07/08/10-alternatives-to-itunes-for-managing-your-ipod/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a step-by-step](http://ipodmanagers.blogspot.com/) to manage iPod Touch and iPhone without iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Sharepod](http://www.getsharepod.com), which is free, runs on Windows and doesn't need iTunes installed.  (It does require the Windows .Net framework, but you probably already have this)

It doesn't need installing, either, so you can copy the executable onto your iPod and run it directly from there.  As long as your iPod Touch can be used as a USB drive (my iPod Classic can) then you can take the program with you wherever you go.  Very handy!